# Should I learn Angularjs first or Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, typescript

I'm a beginner web developer, I decided to learn my first framework so it's my first time to use a framework and I decided to learn Angularjs & Laravel. which one should I start with ?

PS: I code in PHP and I know PHP OOP, also I'm kinda good at JS

Comment: This question all depends on peoples' opinions and opinion-based questions aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow. That being said, just pick one. It doesn't matter which one. After you learn one framework, it becomes much easier to pick up another.

Comment: This question won't last long. This is an open ended question. Find the pro's and con's of each. You won't likely use both. Simply put- Laravel: Server Side View Rendering. AngularJS: Client Side View Rendering

Comment: I mean it's my first framework so I want to know which one is much easier and it's syntax not complex.

Comment: @BellalMohamed The syntax isn't going to be any different than the language you write it in. Laravel will be PHP and Angular will be JS and HTML. Trust me, it really doesn't matter. There are plenty of sources out there to help you along the way.

Comment: @MikeC You're right thanks for your help :)

Comment: its not recommended to ask opinion based questions mate. there is no right answer for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.

Basically, if you want to learn by your the self, I think the best way is to have a project.

Not a huge one which should start a revolution on internet, and that you will stop in two months.

One that you need to use and develop for a long time.
It can be lot of things, I let you think about it.

So if you want to do some JS project (canvas, multimedia streaming etc...), you should learn angularJS.
If you prefer to do some data / or server side project, it is better to learn Laravel.

You probably can find some project which need both of frameworks =) - mapping, or multimedia big data I do not know.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should learn Angular first, as it is comparatively easy then Laravel.

Best tutorial I think for AngularJS is its official free course http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/

I learnt from this videos only, its really helpful